# How to use button behavior with screenmanager without .kv file in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need help on how to use kivy 'button behavior' with screen manager without any .kv file. I have tried but am getting errors.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Buttonbehavior 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Pass

class Screen1(Screen, ButtonBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.welc = Label(text='hi there welcome to my first screen', font_size=15, size_hint=(.26, .26),
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.welc)

#This is where I want the image to have buttonbehaviour and be clickable
        self.goto= ImageButton(source='put_any.png', size_hint=(.3, .2),
                       pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .32}, on_press=(source='put_any.png'), on_release=(source='put_any.png'))
        self.add_widget(self.goto)


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

I know I can do this with button widget but I want to use image and make it use button behavior. Making the image clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class **`ImageButton`**

```py
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image  

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

**Now you can use `ImageButton(source="some/path", on_press=some_function())` in any Layout or App**